# Using Docker COPY to copy files to container without keeping directory structure

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Starting to use Docker here.
Right now im facing an issue with my project, where I need to copy multiple files from multiple directories to the docker image on start up.

Here is my current code

```
FROM heroiclabs/nakama:3.11.0
COPY src/*.lua /nakama/data/modules
COPY src/database/*.lua /nakama/data/modules
COPY src/managers/*.lua /nakama/data/modules
COPY src/modules/*.lua /nakama/data/modules
COPY local.yml /nakama/data
```

What is happening so far is that docker copies only the main.lua file from the starting directory, it either dont copy the remaining ones or copy them with the current data structure.

How can I actually copy it in order to get the lua files from database, manages and modules into the same root directory as main.lua?

To add to this, I get this error on the Nakama console that indicates that a file searched by main.lua module its not found.

```
{"level":"fatal","ts":"2022-04-28T21:19:51.163Z","caller":"main.go:154","msg":"Failed initializing runtime modules","error":"/nakama/data/modules/src/main.lua:2: module economyManager not found:\n\tno field package.preload['economyManager']\n\tno cached module 'economyManager', \nstack traceback:\n\t[G]: in function 'require'\n\t/nakama/data/modules/src/main.lua:2: in main chunk\n\t[G]: ?"}
```

So far so good, the / at the end of each COPY line did not do the trick.

Edit:

This is the full directory structure:

```
src
-database
--luascripts.lua
-managers
--luascripts.lua
-modules
--luascripts.lua
-main.lua
intellisense
-nakama.lua
local.yml
dorckerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

This helps better illustrate the error. As you can se on the log, docker its copying src directory over to nakama/data/modules, what I aim to do is to copy ONLY the content from src, but not the src directory.

Same can be said for other directories to a lesser degree, my aim is to not carry over directory structure to the destination path

Comment: Show us tree structure of your directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your command seems to be right, just add a trailing `/` to the destination docker image's path.

For example,

```
COPY *.lua /nakama/data/modules/
```

Comment: Tryied that and I still get the same error.

`FROM heroiclabs/nakama:3.11.0`
`COPY *.lua /nakama/data/modules/`
`COPY database/*.lua /nakama/data/modules/`
`COPY managers/*.lua /nakama/data/modules/`
`COPY modules/*.lua /nakama/data/modules/`
`COPY local.yml /nakama/data`

The files seems to not get copied to the modules directory, only the main.lua one that its at the root of the directory.

Comment: Try to put ./database/*.lua  instead of database/*.lua

Comment: Still the same error, COPY ./database/*.lua /nakama/data/modules/ and COPY ./database/*.lua /nakama/data/modules

Comment: Could you share the tree structure of your directory and check from where you are running the docker build cmd

Comment: Added directory structure and a better and cleaner error, thx for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The error was on the docker-compose file, I was double mounting a volume and that was causing errors on the whole COPY operation.